# Insufficient data left in message

Tags: postgresql, devart, dotconnect

When we are uploading excel with more than 50,000 records, facing issue like "Insufficient data left in message". I have verified the data with insert statement with previous statement and didn't see any difference.
Could you please check and need support on this.

Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlException (0x80004005): insufficient data left in message
at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.t.a(Boolean A_0, Boolean A_1, Char A_2, Boolean A_3)
at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.g.b(aa A_0)
at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.aa.ai()
at Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlCommand.InternalPrepare(Boolean implicitPrepare, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery)
at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to upload and the definition (actual ddl) of  table you are uploading into.  Post answers as **update to question not as a comment**.

Answer (score 0):

The error "insufficient data left in message" can occur in cases when a value in incorrect format is passed to a table field on the server. For example, if you pass a value 'abcd' (string) for a field of the uuid data type. Or your string data has a null character "\0" in it.

For a more accurate diagnosis, we need a sample of your data and DDL for the database table.

Comment: We have verified the data at granular level and didn't see any issue with data and data type. First time we are getting error at 1 record level. If i put the if condition with the values where i got the error for first time, not getting the error for that particular value and getting error for some other record. We have verified the values of each record and there is no issue with data and data type. Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Please provide us a test project with a sample of your data and DDL for the database table, so that we could reproduce the issue.